# array of hash in Chef databags?

Tags: chef-infra, databags

I am trying to include array-of-hash data in a chef databag item.  Is this supported?  I keep getting error messages about an undefined method.  Here's an example:

Databag item:

```
{
        "id": "BurgerKing",
        "sandwich": "Whopper",
        "nickname": "BK",
        "value_meals":[
                {
                "sandwich":  "Big King",
                "side": "Fries",
                "drink": "Coke"
                },
                {
                "sandwich": "Kids Burger",
                "side": "Apple Slices",
                "drink": "Milk"
                }
        ]
}
```

Template:

```
<!-- I want to go to <%= @restaurant[ 'nickname' ] %> to get a <%= @restaurant['sandwich'] %>. -->
<!-- But there are also value meals... -->
<% @restaurant.value_meals.each do | meal | %>
<!-- <%= meal.sandwich %>, <%= meal.side %>, and <%= meal.drink %> -->
<% end -%>
```

If I only access the sandwich and nickname fields, I'm great, but as soon as I add code to iterate through the value_meals, I get:

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `value_meals' for #<Chef::DataBagItem:0x00000002d07df0>) on line #6:

  4: <!-- I want to go to <%= @restaurant[ 'nickname' ] %> to get a <%= @restaurant['sandwich'] %>. -->
  5: <!-- But there are also value meals... -->
  6: <% @restaurant.value_meals.each do | meal | %>
  7: <!-- <%= meal.sandwich %>, <%= meal.side %>, and <%= meal.drink %> -->
  8: <% end -%>
```

Thanks ahead!!!

And thanks CodeRanger!!!

Adding the below, which fixed it here, since I apparently don't have the knack for formatting comments yet.

```
<!-- But there are also value meals... -->
<% @restaurant['value_meals'].each do | meal | %>
<!-- <%= meal[ 'sandwich' ] %>, <%= meal[ 'side' ] %>, and <%= meal[ 'drink' ] %> -->
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you access hashes in Ruby is via `[]` syntax, so `@restaurant['value_meals'].each` and `meal['side']`.

Comment: Thanks!!!  Modified it to:<!-- But there are also value meals... -->
<% @restaurant['value_meals'].each do | meal | %>
<!-- <%= meal[ 'sandwich' ] %>, <%= meal[ 'side' ] %>, and <%= meal[ 'drink' ] %> -->
<% end -%>

and it worked like a champ!  Apologies for lousy formatting...new to SO.